# Programming Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java

so im programming conways game of life in GUI form. the output is not correct and i dont know why. this is the code that handles the "next generation".

```
for(int i=0; i < ROW; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < COL; j++) {
        if(i > 0 && i < ROW-1 && j > 0 && j < COL -1) {
            if(grid.getButton(i-1, j-1).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i-1, j).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i-1, j+1).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i, j-1).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i, j+1).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i+1, j-1).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i+1, j).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;
            if(grid.getButton(i+1, j+1).getBackground() == Color.BLUE) liveNeighbor++;

            if(grid.getButton(i, j).getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
                if(liveNeighbor == 3) 
                    newGrid.getButton(i, j).setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    if(liveNeighbor > 3 || liveNeighbor < 2) 
                        newGrid.getButton(i, j).setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            liveNeighbor=0;
        }
    }
}
```

maybe im missing something, but im pretty sure this is right. any suggestions?

Comment: btw, BLUE is live, WHITE is dead. also the getButton(i,j) method gets a JButton from a 2d array list[i][j]. grid and newGrid are custom JPanels in GridLayout form with added JButtons.

Comment: I see you handling the birth cases, but what about the death cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if(grid.getButton(i, j).getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
    if(liveNeighbor == 3) 
        newGrid.getButton(i, j).setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        if(liveNeighbor > 3 || liveNeighbor < 2) 
            newGrid.getButton(i, j).setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Your code *only* sets the color if the current tile is dead. If it's alive, it will never become dead. I would write this as:

```
boolean currentlyAlive = grid.getButton(i, j).getBackground() == Color.BLUE;
boolean aliveNextStep = (liveNeighbour == 3) ||
                        (currentlyAlive && liveNeighbor == 2);
newGrid.getButton(i, j).setBackground(aliveNextStep ? Color.BLUE : Color.WHITE);
```

I'd also separate the logical data (a grid of boolean values) from the display part - the "business logic" here shouldn't know anything about colors.

Comment: i didnt use your suggested solution, but i got it to work based on your comment, had to add another else in the else to set to BLUE. thanks for feedback

Comment: @user1459976: Out of interest, why didn't you use my suggestion? I consider it simpler and easier to read, as well as starting along the road of separating out the "business" part from the UI part.

Comment: i guess i like how the code i used is a bit more linear? and i felt like it was missing a small piece, so i wanted to find that instead of replacing the whole thing. also i rarely use boolean variables. but i agree your code is a bit more elegant i suppose